# Calculate ECEF satellite position from TLE

Tags: python, pyephem

I'm calculating the position of satellities using mi location (in latitude-longitude), I want to know what satellities can I see (my receptor) from my position. For this I'm using the help of this [blog](http://libjoe.blogspot.com.co/2009/10/where-is-my-satellite-in-python.html), I'm using **Pyphem**, the library for python, and using the information of the **TLE** files. With this I can know the position but maximum the range of data that I can get with the file, the files are in [this](https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/gps-ops.txt) site.
e.g. The file get info from 12-01-2017 1:00 to 13-01-2017 23:59, I want to know the position for 14-01-2017 13:05
The Question is Can I get a TLE file for tomorrow? or just I can get the file for the day of today?

**UPDATE 1.**

[my code](https://github.com/mikesneider/SatellitalPosition/blob/master/Calculating%20satellites%20with%20Pyphem.ipynb) in python is this:

```
TimeNow = datetime.datetime.now() #"10/01/2017"
Longitude = -73.1198 
Latitude = 7.11392
print TimeNow

sat_alt, sat_az, sat_name = [], [], []

observer = ephem.Observer()
observer.long = '-73.1224429' # '-37.799423'
observer.lat = '7.1388027' # '144.999979'
observer.date = datetime.datetime.now()

GPS_list = 'https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/gps-ops.txt'
GPS2_list = 'http://www.tle.info/data/gps-ops.txt'
GLONASS_list = 'https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/glo-ops.txt'
GLONASS2_list = 'http://www.tle.info/data/glo-ops.txt'
#'http://www.amsat.org/amsat/ftp/keps/current/nasabare.txt').readlines()


tles = urllib2.urlopen(GPS_list).readlines() 

tles = [item.strip() for item in tles]
tles = [(tles[i],tles[i+1],tles[i+2]) for i in xrange(0,len(tles)-2,3)]

for tle in tles:

    try:
        sat = ephem.readtle(tle[0], tle[1], tle[2])
        rt, ra, tt, ta, st, sa = observer.next_pass(sat)

        if rt is not None and st is not None:
            #observer.date = rt
            sat.compute(observer)
            
            #if 'PRN 26' in tle[0]:
                #print "TRUE"
            if TimeNow <= ephem.localtime(st) and TimeNow >= ephem.localtime(rt):
                text = tle[0]
                sat_alt.append(np.rad2deg(sat.alt))
                sat_az.append(np.rad2deg(sat.az))
                
                text2 = text.rsplit(')', 1)[0]
                text3 = text2.rsplit('(', 1)[1]
                sat_name.append(text3)
                print text3, np.rad2deg(ra),np.rad2deg(sa)
    except ValueError as e:
        print e
```

Results:

```
PRN 19 228.755917041 148.703886987
PRN 02 221.648736379 143.285115427
PRN 17 221.556446863 146.188232693
PRN 30 322.13237575 60.4800956664
PRN 06 211.849518618 131.038791151
```

In this exaple I have the information of today (28/02/2017) I in the link I have the TLE file of today, but if I want the information of tomorrow?

thank you

**UPDATE 2:**

You can change the variable `TimeNow` for another date (for example `now + 2 hours`), but I do not find how is the error if with the TLE file of today I try to calculate the position (elevation / azimuth) of tomorrow, or past tomorrow, the error will be too big? how much? (i'm reading [this](https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/supplemental/) trying to find the answer) I hope someone knows it. Thanks.

Comment: Where, specifically, are you getting the values 12-01-2017 1:00 to 13-01-2017 23:59? I do not see those in the file you link to — could you show the code you are using to get those specific dates and times? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I updated the question; with the link, I have the information of today, but if I wanna know the position of the satellites of tomorrow? How can I get that file? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you want to get a satellite's position from its TLE in a period of time, well you can get cartesian coordinates of a satellite's TLE by using the sgp4 library : `pip install sgp4`

```
from sgp4.api import Satrec

from sgp4.api import jday
```

Then you put the first TLE line in the variable s, and the second in the variable t like this :

```
s = '1 25544U 98067A   21035.51324206  .00001077  00000-0  27754-4 0  9998'

t = '2 25544  51.6455 278.9410 0002184 336.6191  80.6984 15.48940116268036'

satellite = Satrec.twoline2rv(s, t)
```

Then you pick the date you want, (year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds) like this :

```
jd, fr = jday(2021, 2, 4, 18, 5, 0) 

e, r, v = satellite.sgp4(jd, fr)
```

And you've got the error `e`, position vector `r`, speed vector `v` in Cartesian coordinates.

https://josephinepicot.medium.com/get-the-cartesian-position-velocity-vectors-of-a-satellite-at-a-given-time-from-a-tle-60d29e31c422

Now, if your satellite is geostationary, it's easy to know what its position will be the next day, but if not, you might be able to plot a time series with the previous position vectors...

Hope it helped!